# Forcing verilator to take loop label given in RTL

Tags: system-verilog, verilator

I want to force the hierarchy of signal to take the loop names given in RTL written in System Verilog.

Example:

```
for (genvar i=0; i<4; i++) begin: GenLabel
```

what I am seeing:

```
hiearchy1.hierarchy2.signal(1)(10)
```

what I need:

```
hiearchy1.hierarchy2.LABEL(1).LABEL(2).signal
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. In the [manual](https://www.veripool.org/projects/verilator/wiki/Manual-verilator#LANGUAGE-LIMITATIONS), under "Language Limitations", it says:

> **Dotted cross-hierarchy references**
>
> Verilator supports dotted references to variables, functions and tasks
>   in different modules. However, references into named blocks and
>   function-local variables are not supported. The portion before the dot
>   must have a constant value; for example a[2].b is acceptable, while
>   a[x].b is not.
>
> References into generated and arrayed instances use the instance names
>   specified in the Verilog standard; arrayed instances are named
>   `{cellName}[{instanceNumber}]` in Verilog, which becomes
>   `{cellname}__BRA__{instanceNumber}__KET__` inside the generated C++
>   code.
>
> Verilator creates numbered "genblk" when a begin: name is not
>   specified around a block inside a generate statement. These numbers
>   may differ between other simulators, but the Verilog specification
>   does not allow users to use these names, so it should not matter.
>
> If you are having trouble determining where a dotted path goes wrong,
>   note that Verilator will print a list of known scopes to help your
>   debugging.

Comment: verilator is actually picking up the labeled hierarchy for some of the signals that are defined within labels. But for others it isn't doing the same. Hence wanted to know is there any way to force verilator to take labeled hierarchy every time.